# Is it possible to prevent automatical closing cmd after running a command if it returns an error?

Tags: java, command-line, process, cmd, runtime.exec

I use:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

where command is something like this:

```
command = new String[]{"cmd.exe", "/c", "start cmd.exe /c " + someCommand}
```

I know that I can use "/k" instead of "/c". But I want my window to stay opened only when "someCommand" returns error. Otherwise, if everything works fine, cmd should close.
I would appreciate any help.Thanks!

Comment: General tip:  Read (and implement) *all* the recommendations of [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html).  Then ignore that it refers to `exec` and build the `Process` using a `ProcessBuilder`.

Answer (score 0):

Read first the Process ErrorStream to see if there are any errors, then use a Scanner to wait from the user input.

```
public static Process p;
public static boolean error=false;
public static void main(String args[]){
    try{
        String command[] = {"cmd.exe", "/c", "start cmd.exe /c " + someCommand}
        p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
        Thread tracer = new Thread (new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                try {
                    InputStream is=p.getErrorStream();
                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (is));
                    while (true) {
                        String s = br.readLine ();
                        if (s == null || s.trim().isEmpty()){
                            break;
                            }
                        System.out.println ("Command error: "+s);
                        error=true;
                    }
                    is.close ();    
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace ();
                }
            }
        });
        tracer.start ();
        p.waitFor();
        if(error){
            System.out.println("There are some errors. Press <Enter> to finish.");
            Scanner scanIn = new Scanner(System.in);
            scanIn.nextLine();
            scanIn.close();
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Error "+e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

This works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Use inputStream() function .. It will not prevent the window from closing, but will redirect it to your console in eclipse (or something else) and there, you can do everything you want to do in a cmd window . You will have your cmd window in your console (literally.).. I think its better to use ProcessBuilder for your kind of thing.. Interestingly, even I am looking for a way to achieve this for some project...

Answer (score -1):

If you use `cmd.exe /k cmd /c` then it will close if no error occurs.